# LINQ to XML Take next node from XML

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML

```
 <File Path="NA">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>               
               <DocType>Invoice</DocType>                              
           </Fields>
 </File>
 <File Path="C:\tmp\test.pdf">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>       
               <DocType>Check</DocType>               
           </Fields>
 </File>
 <File Path="NA">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>               
               <DocType>PO</DocType>                              
           </Fields>
 </File>
 <File Path="NA">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>               
               <DocType>300</DocType>                              
           </Fields>
 </File>
 <File Path="NA">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>               
               <DocType>Invoice</DocType>                              
           </Fields>
 </File>
 <File Path="C:\tmp\test2.pdf">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>       
               <DocType>Bill</DocType>               
           </Fields>
 </File>
```

I am looking to take the File Node/Element that follows any time the DocType element is Invoice.

I have tried using the following Linq:

```
    var files = xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
     .Where(e => e.Element("Fields").Element("DocType").Value == "Invoice")
            .Skip(1).ToList();
```

But that is just returning all the file elements with the Invoice Doc Type skipping the first one. I need the correct linq syntax to get the following nodes/elements. Basically any node that follows the Invoice DocType node. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<File Path="C:\tmp\test.pdf">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>       
               <DocType>Check</DocType>               
           </Fields>
 </File>
<File Path="C:\tmp\test2.pdf">
           <Fields>
               <Side>F</Side>       
               <DocType>Bill</DocType>               
           </Fields>
 </File>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with expected results? Do you want all `Invoice` elements back, or do you want `Check` and `Bill` instead? It's not 100% clear to me.

Comment: You want to use [`ElementsAfterSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345729(v=vs.110).aspx) with `.SelectMany(x => x.ElementsAfterSelf().Take(1))` instead of the `Skip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter will only return the invoices.  You need to project the following file element by using  [`ElementsAfterSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345729(v=vs.110).aspx) .

```
var files = xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
    .Where(e => e.Element("Fields").Element("DocType").Value == "Invoice")
    .SelectMany(x => x.ElementsAfterSelf().Take(1))
    .ToList();
```

This will take up to one element after each invoice file element.  Note that if you have two invoices in a row this will include invoices, so you may want to filter those inside of the `SelectMany` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the same result could be achieved using ElementsBeforeSelf:

```
var files = xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
.Where(x => x.ElementsBeforeSelf().LastOrDefault()?
.Element("Fields").Element("DocType").Value == "Invoice").ToList();
```